# PHP - $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] has "&amp;"

Tags: php, modx

In my php script, I'm trying to get the query string ($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']), append it to another url, and then make a redirect.

If I use the query string without any processing, the new url shows "& amp;" for all the "&'s." Therefore the new url won't work.

I print out the $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] and view the page source. It does use "& amp;" for all the "&'s." It doesn't make sense to me and I wonder why. Is it just my server's configuration or PHP's default?

UPDATE: I tested it on MODX CMS using snippet. If running on a regular PHP script, there is no such issue. I guess the problem is with MODX. Any idea?

Comment: urlencode / urldecode

Comment: & amp; is html entity.

Comment: If modx is what is causing the issue, why not generate the query string yourself? Try `echo http_build_query($_GET)` and see if it produces the same result.

Comment: It's simple to achieve what I want, but I'm curious what could cause this.

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea: 
If you use TinyMCE to edit stuff, it changes all `&'s` to `&amp;'s` - that has been driving me crazy for a lot of times. That happens in snippet calls and can be debugged if you either deactivate the rich text editor for a resource or "quick edit" a resource.

Also good practice: put snippet calls into a **chunk**. You can call that chunk without risking the syntax of the snippet call.